# Syntax problems. Knockout. For filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, syntax

I'm working with jquery, Json data and knockout. What i did is to get a data, add to binded table and a filter field for name.

The thing is, that filter field works not as i want it to work. Because it matches the whole word. That is the code:

```
self.filter = ko.observable();
        self.tickets = ko.computed(function () {
            var filter = self.filter(),
                arr = [];
            if (filter) {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.ticketViewModel(), function (item) {
                    if (item.Name() == filter || item.Status() == filter) {
                        arr.push(item);
                    }

                });
            } else {
                arr = self.ticketViewModel();
            }
            return arr;

        });
```

So i'm trying to make that it would start filtering from the first letter. And i found several methods, which should work, but i can't get the result because i always get various errors of syntax. Maybe who have used these could help me out. The code for it:

```
    self.filter = ko.observable().toString().toLowerCase();
    self.tickets = ko.computed(function () {           
        var filter = self.filter(), 
            arr = [];
        if (!filter) {
            arr = self.ticketViewModel();
        } else {
            ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.ticketViewModel(), function (item) {
                if (ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.Name().toLowerCase()), filter)
                    arr.push(item);
            })
        }

        return arr;
    });
```

The last error i got was - Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function on line

```
var filter = self.filter()
```

The same error i got a few times, but after fixing that i get another ones when usually i get back to it again... And sorry for my english. 
I can post the whole code if needed.

Comment: filter is a  string! `self.filter = ko.observable().toString().toLowerCase();`

Comment: I tried this before. After that i get another error :Uncaught referenceError: filter is not defined. on line "!filter". If i do "!self.filter" then i got the same error on line " if (ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.Name().toLowerCase()), filter)". Plus my filter input fills with: "function d(){if(0<arguments.length)return d.pa(c,arguments[0])&&(d.x(),c=arguments[0],d.w()),this;a.k.jb(d);return c}"

Comment: Tried what before? Daniel's comment was that filter **is** a String - so you can't invoke it as if it were a function.  What do you expect the `self.filter()` call to do?  What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Man, i know that it is a String. And in first example it works perfect for matching the whole words. I'm asking to help remake it for matching from the beginning of the word and showed what i get. Yes, maybe i'm doing it wrong, that's why i ask for help

Comment: But what you do think `self.filter()` will do?  **Why** did you write this line - why are you trying to call a function on something you know is a String?  What were you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find an answer myself, finally.

Instead of using ko.util.stringStartsWith(), i'm using a simple Javascript checking. And it works perfectly. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

```
self.filterName = ko.observable('');
            self.filterCompany = ko.observable('');
            self.filterStatus = ko.observable('');
            self.tickets = ko.computed(function () {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.ticketViewModel(), function (rec) {
                    return (
                              (
                                (self.filterName().length == 0 || (rec.Name().toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filterName().toLowerCase()) > -1)) &&
                                (self.filterCompany().length == 0 || (rec.CompanyName().toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filterCompany().toLowerCase()) > -1)) &&
                                (self.filterStatus().length == 0 || (rec.Status().toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filterStatus().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                              )
                           )
                });

            });
```